# Subprocess spaces in path strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I have a strange situation where I have a method that calls an ffmpeg executable from a path twice in the same method - the first time it works, but the second time it doesn't and I can't work out why.

The ffmpeg executable is at the path

```
c:\GUI\My app\ffprobe.exe
```

I'm calling it with the code

```
for n in (self.file_numbers):
    master_file = n + '.mxf' # eg C31_9213.mxf

    # Get Metadata 1st time (WORKS)
    self.mastermeta = self.getMetadata(master_file) 

    # Get metadata for connected parts (DOESNT WORK)
    self.parts_meta = []
    if master_file: # read parts from a sidecar file...
        with open(sidecar, 'r') as sc:
            # sidecar file contains paths - should split '/' lines into list 
            linelist = [line.strip() for line in sc]
            self.parts_from_file = [p.split('/') for p in linelist]

            # OPTION Check parts & get metadata list for parts 
            if self.parts_from_file: 
                for p in self.parts_from_file:
                    part = str(p[-1]) # the last index is a filename C63_4526.mxf
                    print(part, type(part)) # prints filename and type string identical to above example.
                    partmeta = self.getMetadata(part)
                    self.parts_meta.append(partmeta)
```

and the getMetadata function (which works the first time I call it) looks like this...

```
    def getMetadata(self, master_file=None):
        root = "{}/ffprobe.exe".format(self.program_root.replace('\\', '/')) # /path/to/exe

        cmd = "{} -v quiet -print_format json -show_streams -show_format -sexagesimal".format(root)
        args = shlex.split(cmd)
        args.append(master_file) 

        # GETS META FOR MASTER FILES::::
        # run the ffprobe process, decode stdout into utf-8 & convert to JSON
        ffprobeOutput = subprocess.check_output(args).decode('utf-8')
        ffprobeOutput = json.loads(ffprobeOutput)
        ... more ...
        <returns a list>
```

I'm not moving the executable from *C:\My App\ffprobe.exe*, or changing *self.program_root*, and if I comment out the second call to the getMetadata function it works.

The spaces in the path don't cause a problem the first time, but the second time I get an error where the same path is suddenly split by shlex.split into two parts at the space in the folder name....

```
*Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "GUI_5.py", line 450, in <module>
   gui = Main()
   File "GUI_5.py", line 238, in __init__
   self.setupUi(self)
   File "GUI_5.py", line 155, in setupUi
   self.openFolderDialog()
   File "GUI_5.py", line 428, in openFolderDialog
   partmeta = self.getMetadata(part)
   File "GUI_5.py", line 292, in getMetadata
   ffprobeOutput = subprocess.check_output(args).decode('utf-8')
   File "c:\python35\Lib\subprocess.py", line 626, in check_output
   **kwargs).stdout
   File "c:\python35\Lib\subprocess.py", line 708, in run
   output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
   subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['C:/GUI/My', 'app/ffprobe.exe', '-v', 'quiet', '-print_format', 'json', '-show_streams', '-show
   _format', '-sexagesimal', "C45_0031.mxf'"]' returned non-zero exit status 1*
```

Does anybody have an idea why this might happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regardless of why it worked in the first time, you should always quote your command if its path name contains spaces. Change the line that assigns to `cmd` to:

```
cmd = '"{}" -v quiet -print_format json -show_streams -show_format -sexagesimal'.format(root)
```

Comment: I did that already and got what I thought was the same error, but on inspection it now reads the full path including the spaces in the traceback. So it's something else.

Comment: @Xeberdee Then what's the new error message? Before you had the error message of `subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['C:/GUI/My', 'app/ffprobe.exe',...` so it was clearly not parsing the command with the white space correctly.

Comment: Sure - but it does parse it right the first time, and that's what I don't understand. The second error reads 'subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['C:/GUI/My app/ffprobe.exe',...'. It seems the problem is unconnected and regarding the file extention - os. reports mP4 in the sidecar file - and only a lowercase mp4 works as I specified in the code of the first case.

Comment: @Xeberdee I mean, after you added quotes as I suggested to the command, are you getting a different error message? If so, what is it? I don't think you can get the same error message anymore with the quotes in place.

Comment: So yes the path is parsed correctly in quotes. I'll mark your answer as correct.